# Qt Creator design view missing ""Qt quick - Controls 2" palette

Tags: qt-creator, qtquick2

When creating a Qt Quick project, sometimes the new project's design mode view includes a palette for "Qt Quick - Controls 2" components - (Busy Indicator, Check Box, etc.). But in other cases the new project's design view is missing the Controls 2 palette, even though I need them for my project. How to include them? I am using Qt Creator 4.8.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In design view's "Library" pane, click the "Imports" tab and select QtQuick.Controls.2.* (e.g. QtQuick.Controls.2.3) - then the Controls 2 palette appears under the "QML Types" tab.